# Can't access property in render method of React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access a property of the array I get from the json file, but because I'm using Component DidMount it seems like I can't, and it says it is undefined. I'm trying to access perguntas[0] inside of the render method.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Pergunta from './Pergunta';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        perguntas: undefined,
        isLoaded: false
    }
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/perguntas')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({
                perguntas: json.data,
                isLoaded: true
        }))
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
      console.log(this.state.perguntas)
  }

  /*
    sortear = (perguntas) => {
        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        return perguntas[randomIndex]
    }*/

    render() {
            const {perguntas} = this.state
            //let pergunta = this.sortear(perguntas)

            return (
                // testes...

                <div>
                    <div>{JSON.stringify(perguntas[0])}</div>
                </div>


                //<Pergunta pergunta={ perguntaRandom['id'] }/>
            )
        }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is an asynchronous task, so you should treat it as such. Put an `if` statement inside your `render` method that checks for the proper `state`, otherwise show a loading message or something similar.

Comment: On your first render, which will be run immediately before `componentDidMount`,  `perguntas` will always be undefined. Even if you did it in `componentWillMount`, as the commenter above me suggests, the process is asynchronous so you have no guarantee when it will complete. You need to add a case in your render function for what to do when `perguntas` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer. Both of you are right, I did that and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's the first if statement inside render() method.

```
render() {
        const {perguntas, isLoaded} = this.state
        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        else {
            let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
            let pergunta = perguntas[randomIndex]
            let texto = pergunta.texto
            let opcao1 = pergunta.opcao1
            let opcao2 = pergunta.opcao2
            let opcao3 = pergunta.opcao3
            let opcao4 = pergunta.opcao4
            //let imagem = pergunta.urlImagem

            return (
                <Pergunta texto={texto} opcao1={opcao1} opcao2={opcao2} opcao3={opcao3} opcao4={opcao4}/>
            )
        }
    }
```